# Angular2 + async pipe: Get multiple values from a single Observale

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-pipe, angular-pipe

I have a single Service, which returns a single Observable. Now I'm looking for the correct / most efficient way to get multiple results from this Observable without writing too much code.

- `MyService` returns an `Observable<Array<Foo>>`
- `MyComponent` calls `myService.getFoos()` and should output the first 5 elements from the array, and the total length of the array, and the number of elements not shown.

Here's my current code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  foos = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Foo>>([]);

  getFoos() {
    return this.foos.asObservable();
  }
}



@Component({
  template: `
    Total: {{ totalCount | async }}
    Omitted: {{ (totalCount | async) - (maxFiveItems | async).length }}
    <div *ngFor="let item of maxFiveItems | async">
      {{item.bar}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  totalCount: Observable<number>;
  maxFiveItems: Observable<Array<Foo>>;

  constructor(myService:MyService) {
    this.totalCount = myService.getFoos()
        .map(arr => arr.length);

    this.maxFiveItems = myService.getFoos()
        .map(arr => arr.slice(0, 5));
  }
}
```

The result looks fine, but I'm using the `async` pipe 4 times. Which (as far as I know) will result in 4 Subscriptions. This shouldn't be necessary at all I guess (?)

---

Of course I could manually subscribe within the `constructor` of `MyComponent` and then live without `async` pipes. But then I have to take care of unsubscribing myself.

Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing assuming that `myService.getFoos()` somewhere inside uses `share()` operator so all your `async` pipes share the same subscription to the source. If you're using `BehaviorSubject` as in this example then you're fine.

What you mentioned about subscribing yourself in the constructor is what came to my mind immediately. I don't see manual unsubscription as a problem though.

Comment: I don't understang why you should use `share` on a `BehaviorSubject`.

Regarding unsubscription, if you manually subscribe to something that can emit more than one value (this is the case for a behavior subject), then you need to unsubscribe. Otherwise you get a memory leak. Basically you would to that implementing the `OnDestroy` interface in your component.

Comment: Appart from that, I agree with you: @Benjamin approach seems perfectly good.

Comment: I just read about an upcoming Feature in Angular 4: **ngIf with async pipe and let** (see: https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-angular-version-4-50be1c4f3550 ). This could solve some of these multi-subscription scenarios.

Comment: Yes, the new `ngIf` would be probably the easiest way to do this.